# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error during mutual authentication

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm using mutual authentication and Python2. To generate the certificates for the server and client I use the form:

openssl -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.crt req -x509 -nodes -days 365

I wrap the sockets like this:

```
ssl.wrap_socket(s, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, keyfile=keyfile, certfile=certfile)
```

And the following error occurs running connect on the socket on the client side:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 844, in connect
self._real_connect(addr, False)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 835, in _real_connect
self.do_handshake()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 808, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

I read somewhere that it may be an incompatibility between the certificates and this version of python, but am not sure. I can provide the exact version of python 2 (I think python 2.7) and OpenSSL when I'm back on my main computer.

Any help figuring this out is appreciated.

Comment: "...two-factor authentication .."  - do you mean mutual authentication, i.e. client authenticates server and server authenticates client? two-factor is something else. And obviously you are using self-signed certificates which the other party cannot verify since they have no kind of trust anchor for the certificate. That's why the verification fails. It's like having some document claiming that you are you, signed by you - i.e. not way somebody can trust this document.

Comment: In this case I suppose so; right now I just want to get TLS working. I do also separately encrypt communications.

Comment: The ca_certs parameter can be used in ssl_wrap to add trusted certificates. Use it to tell each party that it should trust the certificate of the other. See also https://carlo-hamalainen.net/blog/2013/1/24/python-ssl-socket-echo-test-with-self-signed-certificate for an example.